# Reverse transformations ImageDataGenerator Keras

Tags: image-processing, keras, image-generation

I am looking into reversing the transformations that `ImageDataGenerator` performs on my input image. I am able to get the transformations performed along with the values of the transformations.

Is there a way I can use these values to reverse the transformations using these values?

Comment: If you reverse the transformations you get the original input (which I guess you have). So why would you need to do that?

Comment: It's actually for the test phase. So I apply a transformation to an image to generate a mask for the image. Now, the output mask will be with the augmentation. Since I have the augmentation values; I want to reverse the augmentations on the mask image

Comment: I'm not sure I get the problem. Usually you have a different generator for the test data which doesn't do augmentations. Since you talk about a mask I guess you are doing something like image segmentation. Maybe you should describe better your problem and your approach so that we can better help you.